# Как назначить переменную без инициализации?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

У меня есть длинная строка, которую я не хочу помещать в генератор списка, но которая использует переменную оттуда. Хочется сделать это как-то чисто.
Следующий вариант очевидно не сработает, т.к. name не определена:

```
names = ['name1', 'name2', 'nameN']
question = f'Ооочень длинная строка {name}'
[input(question) for name in names]
```

Такой вариант сработает, но это явно не чистый код:

```
names = ['name1', 'name2', 'nameN']
question = f'Ооочень длинная строка {name}'
[input(f'Ооочень длинная строка {name}) for name in names]
```

Нужен именно генератора списка, т.к. моя ситуация ровно как из этого вопроса https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating

Как быть?

Comment: `question = 'Ооочень длинная строка {}'; [input(question.format(name)) for name in names]` )

Comment: Спасибо, а есть вариант сделать это новым способом, через `f'str {some_var}'` ?

Comment: ЕМНИП, нет, так как в `f-strings` интерполяция происходит во время использования. Т.е. в тот момент, когда вы используете `f-string` все используемые в ней переменные уже должны быть определены. Это противоречит вашим целям

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497625/how-to-postpone-defer-the-evaluation-of-f-strings

Comment: Вначале вы объявляете список с переменными `names = ['Олегу', Василию', 'Ольге']` а дальше перезаписываете этот список подставляя вступление (очень длинная строка) и добавляя к ней имя `names = [input(f'Сколько лет {name}?') for name in names]`. В чем проблема не пойму???

Comment: @ДавидШико, [что делать с ответами на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [`f-string` (PEP-498)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) интерполяция (подстановка) происходит во время вызова `f-string`. Это не позволяет создать строку с необъявленной переменной и позже подставить значение переменной.

В этом случае следует использовать [старые проверенные способы (PEP-3101)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/):

Вариант 1:

```
question = 'Ооочень длинная строка {}'
[input(question.format(name)) for name in names]
```

Вариант 2:

```
question = 'Ооочень длинная строка {name}'
[input(question.format(name=name)) for name in names]
```

---

Также можно попробовать отложить интерполяцию строки на потом, собрав строку из переменных:

```
question_prefix = 'Ооочень длинная строка'
[input(f'{question_prefix} {name}') for name in names]
```